# Reactjs dashboard - multiple instances with an array of parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

** LATEST Fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/cfrapLma/28/

adding chart types -- is there a better way to move this forward -- would the config json be handled via redux -- what is the next step forward. Has anyone tried making a dashboard application using reactjs and d3 before?

---

I am working on a reactjs project and I am keen to output a set of div holders that will contain future chart parameters, like width, height, url service.

++ How do I push and pull about multiple parameters to create different instances of a chart, placeholder..?
++ Is this a good start for creating a dashboard set of components do I need to create a configuration json for what charts, sizes, services I want to absorb.

//config json?

```
 [{
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200,
        "type": "piechart",
        "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"
    }, {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "type": "barchart",
        "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetBoats"
    }]
```

do I need to create a config json that will control the parameters - an array of charts that are needing to be rendered?

```
var MultipleCharts = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="holder1"><PieChart width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} service={this.props.service}/></div>
        <div className="holder2"><PieChart width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} service={this.props.service}/></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

^ this is a hard coded approach and I would need to loop and push through a configuration json so each chart has different properties.

```
<div data-role="piechart" data-width=240 data-height=240 data-service="api.php?mode=GetCars">
```

//Latest Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cfrapLma/24/

here is the first prototype build - whether I would have reactjs handle a stack of charts -- as if this information is coming from a configuration json -- like a dashboard setup.

Or the dashboard configuration is hardcoded on the template -- and reactjs invokes the charting tool.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Charts</title>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="example"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">

var config = [{
        "width": 200,
        "height": 200,
        "type": "piechart",
        "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"
    }, {
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100,
        "type": "barchart",
        "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetBoats"
    }];


var MultipleCharts = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="holder1"><PieChart width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} service={this.props.service}/></div>
        <div className="holder2"><BarChart width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} service={this.props.service}/></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var PieChart = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
                var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
          console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
          // set el height and width etc.
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="piechart" data-role="piechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height} data-service={this.props.service}>pie.
       </div>
    );
  }
});




var BarChart = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function() {
                var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
          console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
          // set el height and width etc.
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="barchart" data-role="barchart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height} data-service={this.props.service}>pie.
       </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <MultipleCharts width="200" height="200" service="api.php?mode=GetCars"/>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);

    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: - What is the best way to architect this --- Essentially keen to do things the reactjs way to render a stack of different parameter based chart holders.

Comment: Is this where the redux comes into play?

Comment: Interesting references --- https://github.com/ruanyf/react-demos#demo11-ajax , https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html , https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/displaying-data.html , https://simonsmith.io/writing-react-components-as-commonjs-modules/ , https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html , https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Alright so using the create-react-app as a base..

I've tried to start cutting up the files. I get an error when I try and put the PieChart/BarChart parts into their respective files -- do I need to modify them as a class?

/src/App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 80px;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

/src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import BarChart from './BarChart';
import PieChart from './PieChart';
import LineChart from './LineChart';

// Allowed types
const typeMapping = {
  PieChart, // In ES6, it is the same as "PieChart": PieChart, 
  BarChart,
  LineChart
};

class App extends Component {

  getChart(config) {
    const { type, ...props } = config;
    return React.createElement(typeMapping[type], props);
  }

  render() {
      var config = this.props.config;

      return (
          <div>
              {config.map((chartConfig, index) => {
                  return (
                      <div key={index} className={'holder' + index}>
                          {this.getChart(chartConfig)}
                      </div>
                  )
              })}
          </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

/src/BarChart.js

```
//barchart
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var $ = require("jquery");

class BarChart extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3", $this);
        // set el height and width etc.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="barchart" data-role="barchart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                data-service={this.props.serviceApi}>bar.
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default BarChart;
```

/src/Index.css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.piechart{
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.barchart{
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.linechart{
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

/src/Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';

var config = [{
  "type": "PieChart",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"
}, {
  "type": "BarChart",
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100,
  "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetBoats"
}, {
  "type": "LineChart",
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100,
  "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetBoats"
}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <App config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

/src/LineChart.js

```
//linechart
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var $ = require("jquery");

class LineChart extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3", $this);
        // set el height and width etc.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="linechart" data-role="linechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                data-service={this.props.serviceApi}>line.
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default LineChart;
```

/src/PieChart.js

```
    //piechart
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    var $ = require("jquery");

    class PieChart extends Component {
        componentDidMount() {
            var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
            console.log("rendered div now engage d3", $this);
            // set el height and width etc.



            var dataset = {
              apples: [53245, 28479, 19697, 24037, 40245],
            };

            var width = 460,
                height = 300,
                radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

            var color = d3.scale.category20();

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .sort(null);

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(radius - 100)
                .outerRadius(radius - 50);

            var svg = d3.select($this[0]).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

            var path = svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(pie(dataset.apples))
              .enter().append("path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
                .attr("d", arc);


        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="piechart" data-role="piechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                    data-service={this.props.serviceApi}>pie.
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    export default PieChart;
```

Comment: I have split up the application -- using the create-react example as a base -- is this correct?

Comment: -- this has listed the charts in a basic formation. But what if I need to nest the charts in a grid structure - and in some ways nest the charts inside a slider/accordion etc..

Comment: I've added a d3 pie chart - so you can get a gist of what I am trying to propose.

Comment: Your code looks much better now :-). I think that the orginal question is answered, if you need further help, please consider to open a new question. Otherwise it becames difficult to follow what's happening.

Comment: Well @ManoloSantos -- what would you say would be the next steps. I think my main concerns now stem more from.  -- handling groups of nested charts, channelling the data of these charts -- wouldn't this come from a redux based component?

Comment: ^ if you answer the questions @ManoloSantos - I will give you the bounty and then try and research prepare your answers for the next round

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't do it like that. You can keep the bounty for someone else. Nevertheless, if any of my answers has been useful to you feel free to upvote them.

Comment: Don't do what, like what - you tell me what the next steps are - I'll put it into another bounty?

Comment: Yes, you should consider to close this issue and open another question, as the original question has been answered. Please, don't reuse the same question and be specific. Maybe I can suggest you to have a look to the [StackOverflow guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help) if you are confused.

Comment: I'm not confused? I am asking you what the next steps would be to prepare the next bounty

Comment: @ManoloSantos bounty paid -- now the next steps -- nested chart blocks, redux data handling, updating data on a particular chart, master/slave chart relationships, communication between the charts/widgets

Comment: @ManoloSantos -- part 2 continues -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087169/reactjs-dashboard-part-2-enhancement-with-redux-nesting

Comment: There is a bounty out -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087169/reactjs-dashboard-part-2-enhancement-with-redux-nesting

Answer (score 1):

So, what you can do is to create fabric method that will return corresponding component based on `config.type`.

Then, you can iterate through all your configs in render method.
And also pass config as props to your component MultipleCharts.

```js
var config = [{
    "width": 200,
    "height": 200,
    "type": "piechart",
    "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"
}, {
    "width": 100,
    "height": 100,
    "type": "barchart",
    "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetBoats"
}];

var MultipleCharts = React.createClass({
    getChart: function(config) {
        switch (config.type) {

            case 'piechart':
                return <PieChart width={config.width} height={config.height} service={config.service} />
            case 'barchart':
                return <BarChart width={config.width} height={config.height} service={config.service} />
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        var config = this.props.config;
        
        return (
            <div>
                {config.map((chartConfig, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className={'holder' + index}>
                            {this.getChart(chartConfig)}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var PieChart = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
        // set el height and width etc.
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="piechart" data-role="piechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                data-service={this.props.service}>pie.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var BarChart = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
        // set el height and width etc.
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="barchart" data-role="barchart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                data-service={this.props.service}>pie.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <MultipleCharts config={config} />,
    document.getElementById('example')
);
```

And please, try to avoid using data-* attributes in React components.

Comment: why should you avoid using data attributes in react components -- the next goal would be to metabolise the data attributes to invoke the d3.js chart

Comment: Your snippet had an error -- {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 30,
  "colno": 24
}

Comment: I've put the code into this jsfiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/cfrapLma/26/

Comment: _ the next step would be for me to PUT - where it says "console.log("rendered div now engage d3");"  -- actual d3.js code that will then pick up the selector -- and do d3.js stuff to render the chart -- it will read these data attributes to give the chart a width, height, dataservice to call on its own. --- so next when it falls into this region of reactjs how would I get the selector of the item that was just rendered?

Comment: Just get it from var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));?

Comment: -- so in reference to the data config -- would this come from a redux component? - After looking at this solution - is this a GOOD - reactjs way of implementing dashboard components?

Comment: Just use React-D3 component for rendering charts. https://github.com/esbullington/react-d3 . And here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/esbullington/jp9dkh1g/

Comment: I have a batch of custom charts -- more specialised than just usual piecharts

Comment: those are useful examples though -- I would have to re-write the custom d3 code kinda like that format

Comment: I have added additional changes using your guidance. Are you able to enhance and improve the example further -- data handling etc..creating a list of charts is one thing, but how would you go about nesting the charts in stacks etc..

Answer (score 1):

Based in @Sergey's answer I have added a couple of modifications to make it really dynamic. Now there is a `typeMapping` object that maps from strings to components. If you want to add a new component, you just need to add it there. For convenience I am using ES6, I hope that you can translate it to ES5 if you need to.

```js
var config = [{
  "type": "PieChart",
  "width": 200,
  "height": 200,
  "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetCars"

}, {
  "type": "BarChart",
  "width": 100,
  "height": 100,
  "serviceApi": "api.php?mode=GetBoats"
}];

var MultipleCharts = React.createClass({
    getChart: function(config) {
      const { type, ...props } = config;
      return React.createElement(typeMapping[type], props);
    },

    render: function () {
        var config = this.props.config;
        
        return (
            <div>
                {config.map((chartConfig, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index} className={'holder' + index}>
                            {this.getChart(chartConfig)}
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var PieChart = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
        // set el height and width etc.
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="piechart" data-role="piechart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                data-service={this.props.serviceApi}>pie.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var BarChart = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function () {
        var $this = $(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this));
        console.log("rendered div now engage d3");
        // set el height and width etc.
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div className="barchart" data-role="barchart" data-width={this.props.width} data-height={this.props.height}
                data-service={this.props.serviceApi}>bar.
            </div>
        );
    }
});

// Allowed types
const typeMapping = {
  PieChart, // In ES6, it is the same as "PieChart": PieChart, 
  BarChart,
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <MultipleCharts config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

```css
.piechart{
  background: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.barchart{
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>

<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: - how do you split the charts up into separate files.

Comment: @The Old County I am not sure of what you mean. Depending on your environment. In ES6, I would use import. In any case, feel free to open a new question or search for existing ones to help you to modularize your application.

Comment: - "to structure the reactjs components - file structure, how to split the components up". - would it be best to use redux in any of the data handling?

Comment: If you're starting from scratch, [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is worth a look, definitely.

Comment: I get an error with that -- npm ERR! missing script: start

Comment: @TheOldCounty Have you followed the instructions literally?, if so, feel free to open a new question describing the steps you have followed and your node/npm/OS versions.

Comment: -- So would reactjs - act like angular and take over the directives/templates -- would I need codeignitor to do that?